# Can the experience in the replay buffer be selected in advance in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

When using a reinforcement learning algorithm with replay buffer such as SAC, the network parameters are updated by batch sampling.
Can it be considered that "good" experience will improve the strategy, and "bad" experience will make the strategy worse?
If this is the case, is it possible to make a judgment before putting the experience into the replay buffer, keep the “good” experience, and directly remove the “bad” experience?
If this doesn't work, what's the reason?

Are there any problems caused by the lack of diversity in the sample? Or does it change the distribution of states?